# Deleting Azure Storage

Tags: azure, storage

I was just playing with Azure and created a VM with storages. Then I deleted the virtual machine and canceled my subscription. I created an another subscription.

**Now - the problem is**: there are storages left (created with my old subscription) which I want to get rid off. The storages seems to be in read-only state. I really can find a way, that how can I delete those storages?

[A snapshot from a list of storages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oqAk.png)

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA6JC.png)

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

If you cancel the subscription, then you do not need to delete the resources - according to the Azure Trust Center, storage will be deleted automatically after some time: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/TrustCenter/Privacy/You-are-in-control-of-your-data

Or you need to reactivate the subscription and delete the resources by creating a support ticket.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-subscription-become-disable/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alexandr!

I want to confirm, that I took the second option, and asked Azure service desk to re-active my closed subscription again. After it was again active, deleting oprhan storages was very easy.

Thanks for your help.

Ville